# Return mock method argument with gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

How can I return mock method argument as ON_CALL Return() action argument?

Mock method:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(foo, int(const std::string&))
```

Test:

```
TEST_F(Test, t) {

    //I'm using parametrized tests, this is only for simplicity
    std::map<std::string, int> results = {{"Apple", 1}};

    ON_CALL(obj, foo(_))
        .WillByDefault(
            Return(results.at(argument_from_foo_method)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out, use `Invoke` action:

```
ON_CALL(obj, foo(_))
        .WillByDefault(
            Invoke([&](const std::string &s) -> int { return results.at(s); });
```